# Has Israel said anything about whether cutting Gaza in two makes any differece with respect to allowing more aid to South Gaza?

Tags: 2023-israel-hamas-war, humanitarian-aid

By several [accounts](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/11/05/gaza-telecom-contact-israel-military-00125443) Israel now controls all the roads across the Gaza Wadi, cutting it in two. Civilians are sometimes allowed by the IDF to pass south.

> [Nov 5]: “Today there is north Gaza and south Gaza,” Rear Adm. Daniel Hagari told reporters, calling it a “significant stage” in Israel’s war against the Hamas militant group.

I'm wondering what the political implications of that might be, with respect to allowing more aid to South Gaza (or not). Basically, is there a "north Gaza and south Gaza" just on the surface or is that true for Hamas as well?

First, have Israeli officials said anything whether they think Hamas fighters in the north are fully isolated from the south by means of tunnels as well? E.g. are there no tunnels suspected under the Wadi due to water leakage etc.? And is the *bulk* of Hamas fighters presumed trapped in the north?

Even if they didn't address that topic at all, have they said anything, more directly, about whether cutting Gaza in two makes any difference with respect to allowing more aid deliveries to the south?

Comment: FWTW, there's a map released by Reuters of approximate IDF control areas on Nov 6. https://www.reuters.com/graphics/ISRAEL-PALESTINIANS/MAPS/movajdladpa/

Comment: Not sure this is about politics? This is more about military strategy?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: I think it has potential political/humanitarian implications as well. E.g. whether more aid to the south could allowed if the bulk of Hamas is presumed trapped in the north, with no way  to get any of that [aid] smuggled in from south Gaza etc. Also, grand-scale strategy Qs are asked here sometimes, see e.g. the one about what's Israel's plan for this war etc. Yes, this is on a slightly smaller scale than that.

Comment: IDF says https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/17qmi93/new_gaza_tunnels_footage_from_idf_idf_says_troops/ so not the strategy egypt used https://www.reuters.com/article/us-palestinians-egypt-tunnels-idUSKCN0ST1N620151104

Comment: @Fizz "...this is on a slightly smaller scale..." I would say very small scale, but I may be mistaken. It's about some tunnels that may or may not play a role or rather not about the tunnels but about what someone else said about these tunnels that may or may not play a role. Probably interesting but still quite far away from politics in my eyes.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution. Well, there's a couple of questions in there, I answered the one more related to politics. This forum is not equipped to speculate about military strategy anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps.

The Israeli Haaretz reports:

> Egyptian channel: Egypt is getting close to achieving a deal for
> humanitarian pause and hostage release Egyptian television channel
> Al-Kahera reports that, according to Egyptian sources, Egypt is in
> advanced negotiations for achieving a humanitarian pause in the strip
> and a prisoner exchange deal. ([HAARETZ](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-11-08/ty-article-live/soldier-killed-in-gaza-biden-confirms-asking-netanyahu-for-humanitarian-pause/0000018b-ad28-d0f8-a39b-fd3a1c820000?liveBlogItemId=1808559527#1808559527))

The Israelis quoting the Egyptians must mean that a humanitarian pause is in the cards.

The Egyptian press:

> Egypt is near to closing a "humanitarian truce" deal in the war in
> Gaza that would involve an exchange of Israeli captives and
> Palestinian detainees, according to informed sources who spoke with Al
> Qahera News TV channel on Wednesday afternoon. ([AO](https://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/1234/511862/Egypt/Foreign-Affairs/Egypt-nears-closing-a-;humanitarian-truce;-deal-in.aspx))